# How can improve a drone's Reaction (defense vs. bullets)?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4, sr4-matrix, drones

How can I increase the Reaction score/defense vs. bullets of a drone?

Looking through commlink upgrades in *Unwired,* I was expecting to find a matrix upgrade which would increase the Response attribute above rating 6. It's a little unfair for a person to have up to 9 dice of Reaction for dodging bullets, but for a drone to have only 6 (IMHO).

The Response Enhancer says that it increases Matrix Initiative; so it doesn't actually increase the Response attribute of the node. Does that mean it doesn't affect dodge rolls? If not, is there any upgrade in Shadowrun 4E that does?

**Edit**

Note that a Shadowrun character can have up to *13* dice to dodge bullets:

```
9 Reaction (augmented) + 4 Combat Sense (adept power)
```

...compared to a max Response for a drone of 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, according to [this](http://forums.shadowrun4.com/index.php?topic=123.0) max 6 dice is a system design decision, but I haven't touched 4e shadowrun in a long while.

Comment: +1; This is a reasonable answer; I agree with the premise that having more than 6 dice in Response could be unbalancing for matrix combat, but that isn't really what I'm interested in. I edited and rephrased the question: I only really care about the drone's ability to dodge bullets. If there's an enhancement that affects the drone's reaction score, that's perfect, even if it doesn't affect the matrix attributes. It may be that there isn't one.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Should I remove my answer? I'm unsure as to protocol here.

Comment: No, I gave you points for the reference =) if I don't come up with any drone mod that addresses the issue, I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Drones may use Defense autosoft to improve their dodge. (SR4A p.246) It is specified that

> A drone equipped with a Defense autosoft can parry against melee attacks (using Defense + Pilot) and **use full defense** (p. 160) against an incoming attack

Using full defense allow to dodge bullets with Reaction + Defense rating (here used instead of Dodge)

Autosofts rating are limited by the drone's autopilot, so the best you can do with out-of-the-box material is 9D6.

For a very small drone, I guess you can ask your GM to give penalty to the shooter, and for a large one, prefer armor.